# black screen after last update when using nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xubuntu, xorg, freeze

I'm using Xubuntu 20.04 with linux kernel 5.10. After a normal update I now can't login anymore. Just before the login menu, the computer freezes.

I was able to login after I removed the nvidia driver, but I can't make the computer run with any of the nvidia drivers installed. I tried nvidia-driver-465 nvidia-driver-460  nvidia-440. Nothing works.

I tried to go back to kernel 5.8, same issue.

I had a similar problem a few weeks ago when using manjaro (moved to ubuntu because of it).

I have no idea what is going on, and I didn't find any clues in the logs.

Comment: Kernek 5.10 is not standard in 20.04. And how exactly are you installing the Nvidia drivers?

Comment: I also tried using kernel 5.8, same problem. I used the software updater.

Comment: "Software updater" (whatever that is) don't install additional drivers, Additional Drivers, a tab at Software & Updates do. The latter is the recommended way. And don't forget to disable Secure Boot in UEFI.

Comment: Yes I'm talking about the Software & Updates and yes I disabled Secure Boot in UEFI.

Comment: FYI the problem is a bug involving Nvidia automatic X configuration and displayport. Your condescending answers didn't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem! I fixed it as follows: First you have to get into a shell.

If your system does not start up, select Advanced Options in the Grub menu and boot into recovery mode. From there enable Networking and then drop into root shell.

Then purge all nvidia driver related packages:

```
apt purge nvidia-* libnvidia-* xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-*
```

Now install the server versions of them:

```
apt install nvidia-driver-460-server
```

In my case, I had to install the dependencies manually before it worked:

```
apt install xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460-server nvidia-utils-460-server libnvidia-encode-460-server nvidia-compute-utils-460-server
```

Then reboot:

```
shutdown -r now
```

Comment: I tried all of that, it didn't work. I found the culprit rough. Looks like there is a bug envolving NVIDIA drivers, some graphics cards, displayport port, and high resolution displays. The solution I found was too replace my displayport with an HDMI card. People that use quadros a doomed do. That anyways

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The culprit looks to be the displayport connector. For some reason the automatic xorg configuration done by Nvidia, doesn't work well for some cards when connected to high resolution displays through displayport.

Connecting the PC to the monitor using an HDMI cable solves the problem. For people that do need display port, you might be able to manually config the x files. I had not luck with that.